# Pressure bag moulding Vs Vacuum bag moulding

Tags: manufacturing-engineering, molding

What are there pro and cons of each method? In which industries were/are these molding techniques used? Why has vacuum bag molding supplanted pressure bag molding?

Comment: Looking it up, it seems vacuum bagging has less equipment. You don't need a rigid plate for the pressure bag to push against. I have a vacuum bag setup and if it required a large rigid plate, I wouldn't have one.